# Implementing a "sun effect" glare on a UIView when tilted

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, core-motion

Say I have a regular UIView that takes up the whole screen and is a solid color. Ideally I want to be able to tilt the screen and artificially create a glare on the screen when tilted to and fro to mimic a glare from the sun.

I've gotten as far as looking into SKLightNode for specular, diffuse and ambient lighting and I know how to access accelerometer/gyroscope data through CoreMotion but I'm a little lost on how to connect the dots or if I'm even looking in the right place.

What frameworks would be most applicable to use in order to achieve something like this?

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DuncanC Thanks for the feedback. I modified the question to minimize the scope for an answer.

Comment: i think that's a great idea btw